# Combine FILTER and ArrayFormula in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet in Google:

[image]

I need set a ARRAYFORMULA function at "Valor" column, because the rows are autogenerated by a Google Form, and I need apply de same formula for new rows.

How can I combine filter and arrayformula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your data:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C)`

[image]

Comment: Hello! the formula for D column is =FILTER(A2:C2;A2:C2<>""), because I need find the first cell value not empty. Thanks